# Calling the function multiple times

Tags: function

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

double fnCalculate(void);

    int main(void){

         float grosspay, netpay, tax, deduction, regular, overtime;
         char choice;


           printf("Enter:\n");
           printf("Regular:\t\n");
           scanf("%f", &regular);
           printf("Overtime:\t\n");
           scanf("%f", &overtime);
           printf("Deduction:\t\n");
           scanf("%f", &deduction);
           printf("Grosspay= %.2f\n", grosspay = (regular + overtime)-deduction);

           printf("Tax:\t\n");
           scanf("%f", &tax);
           printf("netpay= %.2f\n\n", grosspay - tax);
                double fnCalculate(){
                    printf("Enter:\n");
                    printf("Regular:\t\n");
                    scanf("%f", &regular);
                    printf("Overtime:\t\n");
                    scanf("%f", &overtime);
                    printf("Deduction:\t\n");
                    scanf("%f", &deduction);
                    printf("Grosspay= %.2f\n", grosspay = (regular + overtime)-deduction);

                    printf("Tax:\t\n");
                    scanf("%f", &tax);
                    printf("netpay= %.2f\n\n", grosspay - tax);
                    }
                      printf("Do you want to calculate again? 1-yes, 0-no\n");
                      scanf("%s", &choice);
                            if(choice == '1'){
                            return fnCalculate();
                                     }
                            else if(choice == '0'){
                            printf("Bye!");
                                     }
   getch();
```

}

I just want the process to repeat endless times. But the problem is, I can only calculate again for two times with this code so, how should I do it?

I am using scanf because it's what our professor prefer. I would appreciate other corrections with my code since I'm just a beginner in c programming.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a loop of some kind:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html

If it's an indeterminate number of multiplications you want to process, you'll want to use a 'WHILE' loop with some kind of sentinel.

I noticed that you also declare a function 'fnCalculate' that does exactly what you do in your main block before its declaration. You could move the declaration of your variables inside your function and then reduce all code between main header and fnCalculate declaration into a single call to fnCalculate(). Remember that the main point of functions is to encapsulate code that you want to reuse. Also, you have your function 'fnCalculate' declared to return a double, but it currently returns nothing. If you'd actually like it to return the netpay value, make sure you do that explicitly (e.g., return grosspay-tax;). Otherwise, declare the function as void.

Final product would look something like:

```
#includes...
void fnCalculate(void) {
   float grosspay, netpay, tax, deduction, regular, overtime;
   printf("Enter:\n");
   printf("Regular:\t\n");
   scanf("%f", &regular);
   printf("Overtime:\t\n");
   scanf("%f", &overtime);
   printf("Deduction:\t\n");
   scanf("%f", &deduction);
   printf("Grosspay= %.2f\n", grosspay = (regular + overtime)-deduction);
   printf("Tax:\t\n");
   scanf("%f", &tax);
   printf("netpay= %.2f\n\n", grosspay - tax);
   // here is where you'd return. I've chosen void, so no return.
}

int main (void) {
   // declare sentinel
   int continue = 1;
   while (continue) { 
      // note, 1 will evaluate to true, 0 will evaluate to false
      // function does the bulk of our work
      fnCalculate();
      // modify our sentinel dependent on user input
      printf("Do you want to calculate again? 1-yes, 0-no\n");
      scanf("%s", &continue);
   }
   print("Bye!");
   return 0;
}
```

Also, notice the code is much easier to read when the brackets line up.

Hope this helps.

Steve

Comment: Hi! I think I've solved this problem but forgot to post it here years ago. Thank you for the reply though.